# CDN for executable files

Tags: performance, wordpress, cdn

On my new [site](http://thinkzarahatke.com), I display around 50-60 thumbnails per page using my one of the [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amtythumb/).

**About plugin:**

1. For every requested post id, it
   extracts content for the post from
   DB and find out the image url.
2. It generates thumbnail for found
       image URL.

I wanted to minimize number of hits to the server in generating the thumbnail. If server is cache enabled then it can reduce many of the hits. But i was willing to separate the 2nd part from the plugin and to host it on any other server/CDN where i/other can request to generate thumbnail without any charges.

I tried free webhosting provider. but i felt they are generally slow/down maximum of time.

Please suggest the approach or CDN, if any...

Or any online image api which can resize/zoom/crop/edit an image, if i pass the image url.

Comment: What's your question? I'm not sure what you are asking here...

Comment: Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) - http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: @pav, from the question... "where i/other can request to generate thumbnail without any charges"

Comment: @yakatz http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing 
AWS Free Usage Tier* As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, 15GB of data transfer in, and 15GB of data transfer out each month for one year.

Comment: @pav, Not really free; they could start charging or the program could also be discontinued with zero notice (Amazon has done it before) "These free tiers are only available to new AWS customers and are available for 12 months following your AWS sign-up date. When your free usage expires or if your application use exceeds the free usage tiers, you simply pay standard, pay-as-you-go service rates (see each service page for full pricing details). **Restrictions apply**; see offer terms for more details."   Don't get me wrong, I use S3 a lot and my bill is very small, but it is certainly not free.

Comment: @articlestack, please conclude with a concrete question; maybe like this: "I would like to know how to make my plugin cache the images it generates or I would like to find an online service that can generate the thunbnails for me on every page load". I can help you with the former, not with the latter. As I said: TANSTAAFL

Comment: @yakatz, I think it is already summrized. I can write the code for caching. But my interest is in uploading thumbnail generation script to some server. So the server hits can be reduced. Or in some free API which can generate thumbnail for my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very hard (almost impossible) to find a reliable server/CDN that will generate thumbnails of images for free.
[TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

Assuming your plugin uses several standard wordpress function, you might be able to use another plugin which takes the generated thumbnails and uploads them to another server.  I recommend W3 Total Cache.

You could also try [CoralCDN](http://www.coralcdn.org/) to take some load off your server.

So: You can use CoralCDN (or similar) and just point the URLs of your thumbnails through it, or you can have a caching plugin like W3TC upload the files to an almost-free site like Amazon S3.

Comment: 1) thumbnail generation part is not using any wordpress function. 2)I need not to minimize load of my server only. It is related to all users who uses my plugin.